# Why is my S3 pre-signed request invalid when I set a response header override that contains a "+"?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon .NET SDK to generate a pre-signed URL like this:

```
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AsActionResult(string contentType, string contentDisposition)
{
    ResponseHeaderOverrides headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
    headerOverrides.ContentType = contentType;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentDisposition))
    {
        headerOverrides.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }

    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
               .WithBucketName(bucketName)
               .WithKey(objectKey)
               .WithProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS)
               .WithExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(6))
               .WithResponseHeaderOverrides(headerOverrides);

    string url = S3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);

    return new RedirectResult(url, permanent: false);
}
```

This works perfectly, except if my `contentType` contains a `+` in it. This happens when I try to get an SVG file, for example, which gets a content type of `image/svg+xml`. In this case, S3 throws a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

The error message shows the `StringToSign` like this:

```
GET 1234567890 /blah/blabh/blah.svg?response-content-disposition=filename="blah.svg"&response-content-type=image/svg xml
```

Notice there's a space in the response-content-type, where it now says `image/svg xml` instead of `image/svg+xml`. It seems to me like that's what is causing the problem, but what's the right way to fix it?

Should I be encoding my content type? Enclose it within quotes or something? The documentation doesn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

This bug has been [fixed as of Version 1.4.1.0](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314990#316226) of the SDK.

---

#### Workaround

This is a confirmed [bug in the AWS SDK](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314990#315136), so until they issue a fix I'm going with this hack to make things work:

Specify the content type exactly how you want it to look like in the response header. So, if you want S3 to return a content type of `image/svg+xml`, set it exactly like this:

```
ResponseHeaderOverrides headerOverrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
headerOverrides.ContentType = "image/svg+xml";
```

Now, go ahead and generate the pre signed request as usual:

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
  .WithBucketName(bucketName)
  .WithKey(objectKey)
  .WithProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS)
  .WithExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(6))
  .WithResponseHeaderOverrides(headerOverrides);

string url = S3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

Finally, "fix" the resulting URL with the properly URL encoded value for your content type:

```
url = url.Replace(contentType, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(contentType));
```

Yes, it's a dirty workaround but, hey, it works for me! :)

Answer (score 3):

Strange indeed - I've been able reproduce this easily, with the following observed behavior:

- replacing `+` in the the URL generated by `GetPreSignedURL()` with its encoded form `%2B` yields a working URL/signature

  - this holds true, no matter whether `/` is replaced with its encoded form `%2F` or not
- encoding the contentType upfront before calling `GetPreSignedURL()`, e.g. via the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332872%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), yields invalid signatures regardless of any variation of the generated URL

Given how long this functionality is available already, this is somewhat surprising, but I'd still consider it to be a bug - <strike>accordingly it might be best to inquiry about this in the [Amazon Simple Storage Service forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=24).</strike>
<strike>**Update:** I just realized you asked the same question there already and the bug got confirmed indeed, so the correct answer can be figured out over time by monitoring the [AWS team response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314990#315136) ;)</strike>
**Update:** This bug has been [fixed as of Version 1.4.1.0](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=314990#316226) of the SDK.

Comment: you're absolutely right. In fact, I tried out exactly what you did and came to the same conclusions right after I posted the question! :) Although the URL works when you encode it, I've noticed that the actual Content Type header in the response is sometimes messed up.