# Getting a pre-authenticated URL to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, auto-update

I am attempting to use an S3 bucket as a deployment location for an internal, auto-updating application's files.  It would be the location where the new version's files are dumped for the application to puck up on an update.  Since this is an internal application, I was hoping to have the URL be private, but to be able to access it using only a URL.  I was hoping to look into using third party auto updating software, which means I can't use the Amazon API to access it.

Does anyone know a way to get a URL to a private bucket on S3?

Comment: This part of the S3 dev guide hints that it is possible, but doesn't explain where to get the components of the URL http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use one of the available [AWS Software Development Kits (SDKs)](http://aws.amazon.com/code/), which all implement the respective methods to generate these URLs by means of the *GetPreSignedURL()* method (e.g. Java: [generatePresignedUrl()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html), C#: [GetPreSignedURL()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_GetPreSignedURL.htm)):

> The GetPreSignedURL operations creates a signed http request. Query
>   string authentication is useful for giving HTTP or browser access to
>   resources that would normally require authentication. When using query
>   string authentication, you create a query, specify an expiration time
>   for the query, sign it with your signature, place the data in an HTTP
>   request, and distribute the request to a user or embed the request in
>   a web page. A PreSigned URL can be generated for GET, PUT and HEAD
>   operations on your bucket, keys, and versions.

There are a couple of related questions already and e.g. [Why is my S3 pre-signed request invalid when I set a response header override that contains a “+”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051650/why-is-my-s3-pre-signed-request-invalid-when-i-set-a-response-header-override-th) contains a working sample in C# (aside from the content type issue Ragesh is experiencing of course).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I was hoping to do it without writing a little app for it.  I ended up finding an online one, but in the end, decided to use CloudFTP as an FTP endpoint to my S3 bucket.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855109/amazon-s3-ftp-interface